# How to install graphql to angular 5.2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, graphql

I want to install graphql apollo to angular with the 5.2 version. Which packages do I need to use, and which versions?

Comment: I don't think apollo-angular supports v5.2

Comment: It sholud be [this](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/releases/tag/1.0.0) version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular cli

```
ng add apollo-angular
```

Comment: this will not work

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Angular 5 does not support ng add